# Signature invalid error while calling Google API for RequestToken

Tags: c#, oauth, google-api

I am calling Google API for RequestToken and I am using OAuhtBase to generate my signature. My code looks like following:

```
 public Uri BaseURL
        {
            get { return new Uri("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken");  }
            set { }
        }
        public string ConsumerKey
        {
            get { return "anonymous"; }
        }
        public string Nonce
        {
            get { return oAuthBase.GenerateNonce(); }
        }
        public string SignatureMethod
        {
            get { return "HMAC-SHA1"; }
        }
        public string Signature { get
        {
            string url;
            string requestParams;
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oAuthBase.GenerateSignature(BaseURL, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, string.Empty, string.Empty,
                                               "GET", Timestamp, Nonce, out url, out requestParams));
        }
        }
        public string Timestamp
        {
            get { return oAuthBase.GenerateTimeStamp(); }
        }
        public string Scope
        {
            get { return "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"; }
        }
        public string Callback
        {
            get { return "www.contestfactory.com"; }
        }


          public string GenerateURL()
          {

             var returnURL = new StringBuilder(BaseURL.ToString());

             returnURL.Append("?");
             returnURL.Append("oauth_consumer_key=" + ConsumerKey);
             returnURL.Append("&oauth_signature_method=" + SignatureMethod);
             returnURL.Append("&oauth_signature=" + Signature);
             returnURL.Append("&oauth_timestamp=" + Timestamp);
             returnURL.Append("&oauth_nonce=" + Nonce);
             returnURL.Append("&oauth_callback=" + Callback);
             returnURL.Append("&scope=" + Scope);

              return returnURL.ToString();

          }
```

Now, when my javascript tries to browse to the URL that has been generated by this code. It comes back with following error on the browser:

> signature_invalid
>   base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetRequestToken&oauth_callback%3Dwww.contestfactory.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3Danonymous%26oauth_nonce%3D400857%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1334790691%26scope%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fuserinfo.profile

I am not sure what part of the signature can be wrong because i am passing it all the required parameters and they all are basic strings. any idea?

Comment: where does `oAuthBase` come from?

Comment: OAuthBase is basically a Library that I saw a lot of people using http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs

Comment: long shot: is the time on your computer correct?

Comment: Also, i figured that when it is calling GenerateURL() and when it is calling GenerateSignature() timestamp  and Nonce would be different. So I moved them both to a constructor making sure both functions get the same values but no luck so far.....

Comment: I also tried using another class for generating signature and with the signature that it generates, answer is still invalid....

Comment: You should update the Nonce code in your snippet. I just submitted an answer about this before reading this comment.

Comment: Hi Andrew, i am sorry for not beig detailed enough on this. I am submitting Nonce, Timestamp and Signature all just before building URL. But no luck...